# asp.net MVC-3 video tutorials?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know any good link for asp.net MVC-3 video tutorials. I have book but Video tutorials are good and easy to learn fast.

Comment: There are Pluralsight On-Demand training videos in http://www.asp.net/mvc I've found them really easy to follow and informative.

Comment: Did you even check the website I posted? Microsoft paid for the videos and let us watch it for free!

Comment: this can be easily googled and found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love the following two. Its about ASP.NET MVC2 but motivating, fun and a very good start.

- [ASP.NET MVC 2: Basics, Introduction by Scott Hanselman](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Basics-Introduction-by-Scott-Hanselman)
- [ASP.NET MVC 2: Ninja Black Belt Tips by Scott Hanselman](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Ninja-Black-Belt-Tips-by-Scott-Hanselman)

#### more

- [ASP.NET MVC 3 - Videos](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos)
- [Session Recordings from mvcConf 2 - 27 Videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcconf)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to dknaacks answer, I did not see this one, but I think is pretty good:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 – 101 - From beginner to advanced by Scott Hanselman (DevDays-2011)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays002)

There's also a great free course on MicrosoftVirtualAcademy: [Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mvc3+.net

theres lots of good videos on youtube

also lots of stuff on channel9 if you want more official (MS) stuff. http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/asp.net+mvc

All depends on what specifically you want to learn in MVC